# SSIS Inserting Records into table in the same order in flat file

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a flatfile that looks like the first set. I have a table with an auto incrementing primary key field. Using SSIS how can I guarantee when I import that data that it keeps the record order as specified in the flatfile? I'm assuming that when SSIS reads the file that it will keep that order as it inserts into the database. Is this true?

```
In File: 
   RecordType |  Amount
    5               1.00
    6               2.00
    6               3.00
    5                .5
    6               1.5
    7                .8
    5                .5
```

In a Database Table

```
ID | RecordType |      Amount   
1        5               1.00
2        6               2.00
3        6               3.00
4        5                .5
5        6               1.5
6        7                .8
7        5                .5
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my experience it will always load in the order of the input file if you are using an autoincrement ID that is also the clustered index.

Here is a similar discussion that has a couple ideas.  Particularly preprocessing the file or using a script component as the source.  You may want to take one of those routes because the fact that it may behave the way you want by default does not mean it always will.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1300952-364-1.aspx

Comment: ps - There really should be some logic to ordering so that you can use sorts / order by clause.  If the logic exists in the application that is creating the flat file then some kind of field should be included in the file to specify the order.  That is for folks who have that option which many of us are not.

Comment: thx for the link, using script component I added line numbers at the end of each line before processing the data into a table

Answer (score 0):

Just to be safe, I'd add a Sort Transformation in your SSIS package, you can choose the column you want sorted and how it's sorted. This should ensure it reads it the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thew order doesn't matter in a Table.  It only matters in a Query.